# Need a regex pattern to resolve the email validation of Inputs in JavaScript for Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, input, html-email

Need to solve the email validation by using a Regex pattern, The Regex pattern should solve all the possibilities that are mentioned in the below link.

http://onlinetraining.etestinghub.com/email-validation-test-cases/

Already build 50% of pattern but it is not working for all test cases.

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9+*-]+[.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}[^(web)^(.)][a-zA-Z]+[.]?[a-z]?[a-z]?[a-zA-Z0-9*]$

My pattern validation is not passing the tester's test cases.

Comment: please also read here [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and why it is usally counter productive to do so.

Comment: @jps: you have a spelling error in your copy-paste comment: `usually` has two "u"s.

Comment: @halfer thanks for th hint ;-)